# HTML 5 canvas how can I extract and store an image from spritemap?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm also curious to know if this is a best practice.

I load a sprite map:

```
canvas = $('#GameCanvas')[0];
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// load sprite map
spriteMap = new Image();
spriteMap.src = "resources/spritemap.png";
```

Now I've loaded my sprites, I want to draw them on the screen. I can do so by using `context.drawImage(..)` but:

- I don't know if this is the best way, instead of just extracting each image I want and storing them separately eg. `var playerCharacter = [cut the image out of the sprite map]`
- I want to colorise the images. If I pull out a 'white' sprite, I may then want to colorise it red, green, etc. I don't know how to do this yet, but it will probably require creating a new colorised `Image` so I'd have to pull it out of the spritemap anyway. I don't want to be recolorising constantly.

Any idea the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

**Performance using sprites**

Phrogz has some useful FPS tests for CSS vs Canvas here: [Efficiency of <canvas> and <div>s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009128/efficiency-of-canvas-and-divs)  They are live tests so you can run them in the environments you want to test.

**Recoloring sprites**

If you want to quickly take your white sprite and create red, green and blue sprites from it, you can use **globalCompositeOperation=”source-in”** to do that with very little work.  Just use an image editor to create a cutout of the part of the image you want to recolor.  Then use the code below to automatically create different colored sprites.  I did the mask below in Photoshop using the magic want tool – 2 minutes tops!

Original Fish + Mask = Green Fish

[image][image][image]

Of course, you can create any color you want...even patterns instead of solid colors!

Here’s code.  You will probably have to create your own image and mask because of CORS – stupid CORS !!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
      canvas{border:1px solid red;}
      #wrapper{ position:relative;}
      #overlay,#base{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}

  </style>

  <script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("overlay");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,overlay.width,overlay.height);
    }
    img.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/fish%20overlay.png";

    function draw(red,green,blue) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
      ctx.fillStyle="rgb("+red+","+green+","+blue+")";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(0,0,overlay.width,overlay.height);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }

    $("#red").click(function(){ draw(255,0,0); });
    $("#green").click(function(){ draw(0,255,0); });
    $("#blue").click(function(){ draw(0,0,255); });

  });

  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="red">Red Fish</button>    
    <button id="green">Green Fish</button>
    <button id="blue">Blue Fish</button>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img id="base" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/fish.png" width=350 height=250>
        <canvas id="overlay" width=350 height=250></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh that is nice! Thanks for the masking tip :)

Comment: The main question I'm asking though is, should I draw straight from the spritemap, or in my init() method should I separate the spritemap into different images?