# Re-drawing the canvas or moving it?

Tags: html, performance, canvas, render

I need to draw a line that moves from left to right over the screen. Currently I'm just calling .clearRect() everytime, and draw it again, 1 pixel further. However, another possibility would be to draw the canvas once, and move it's CSS position across the screen.

Which scenario would be preferred for performance and why?

Comment: As always, be sure you verify with your own performance tests, but css is probably going to be faster.  See this comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842872/performance-of-moving-image-on-web-page-via-css-vs-html5-canvas

Answer (score 0):

Moving, or "transforming" is always going to be much faster.

You're on the right track, but this is already built into Canvas. Here's a link on how to accomplish this:

[Canvas Transform Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transform-translate-tutorial/)

[Canvas Transform](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_transform.asp)

Comment: I think OP is talking about moving with CSS--not canvas transforms ;)

Comment: Ahh, now I'm curious as to what he's doing :)